# Qt Quick move box with random movements

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I'm trying to create a box that has some kind of Brownian motion (i.e. it keeps moving in random fashion) while the user can interact with it.

The interaction part works and is shortened below to resizing the height below.

The browian part doesn't work - I get two warnings at runtime:

```
[W] unknown:29 - file:.../EvasiveButton.qml:29:76: Unable to assign int to QEasingCurve
[W] unknown:29 - file:.../EvasiveButton.qml:29: ReferenceError: randomNumber is not defined
[W] unknown:24 - file:.../EvasiveButton.qml:24:54: Unable to assign int to QEasingCurve
```

So it appears i have at least the issue that my function randomNumber is not recognized. But moving it elsewhere doesn't seem to help.

Secondly, where do those warnings for ints to QEasingCurve come from?

The code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle {

    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    color: "black"
    focus: true

    Rectangle {
        x: 60
        y: 60
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: parent.height += 50
        }
        Behavior on height {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 200; easing: Easing.OutInQuint}
        }
        SequentialAnimation on x {
            id: brownianMotionX
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            NumberAnimation {to: 40+randomNumber(); duration: 200; easing: Easing.OutInQuint}

        }
        function randomNumber() {
            return Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`randomNumber()` is not available where you are calling it.  Either move it up so it's declared before it's used, or give an `id` to your inner `Rectangle` to call it explicitly.

The easing errors are because you are trying to assign an easing curve *style* to a complete `QEasingCurve` - that's not going to work.  So set the curve style specifically:

```
easing.type: Easing.OutInQuint
```